# bash ,escaping an apostrophe within a SQL statement within bash

Tags: bash

I am attempting to read a text file containing a very long list of words and inserting them and their length into a database for further analysis.

The script i have works until it reaches a word with an apostrophe. What I have currently is:

```
#!/bin/bash
inputfile="words.txt"
cat $inputfile | while read word; do
    echo "INSERT INTO words (word, word_size) VALUES ('$word', CHAR_LENGTH('$word'));"
done | mysql -u root -p crossword
```

The error given is :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 170: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's', CHAR_LENGTH('abbey's'))' at line 1
```

Comment: You switch to a language that provides a proper library for passing parameters to a SQL statement, rather than trying to construct a statement using string operations.

Comment: Yea I could have used PHP but for such a small thing to be used once but on a very large list of words (800k words), would not bash be faster?

Comment: First of all, please echo your SQL statements to standard output by removing your pipe and mysql command.  Then, execute each SQL statement manually on the command line (properly quoting it) in order to identify which statement fails (all of them or only some), and then manually debug that statement.  Once you know what is wrong with the SQL statement you generate, then you can ask how to put in in a script if you cannot figure it out.

Comment: @JohnCogan, ...sometimes correctness is more important than speed. What you implement with bash will certainly be faster, but it won't necessarily be *correct* -- there are a lot of corner cases here around characterset conversion.

Comment: @JohnCogan, ...take a look at why PHP went through so many mysql_escape functions, and the security vulnerabilities that resulted from the early, naiive ones -- if it was so easy you could have a piece of bash that doesn't know which characterset your SQL server is configured for do it, then they would have gotten it right the first time.

Comment: @JohnCogan, ...setting aside security (which is certainly the most important concern), the other thing is that re: a "very large list", that's actually an argument *against* using native bash -- external tools take longer to start up, but usually run faster once they're going. If your PHP reads all your input and writes all your output at one pass, then it should perform adequately. Though using bash *or* PHP to escape your data is bad form -- instead of escaping it at all, you should be passing it out-of-band.

Comment: @JohnCogan, ...that is to say: Escaping is only necessary *because you're passing data and code* (in this case, the code being SQL) *in the same stream*. If you didn't, do that, and used bind variables for your data, then with a well-designed library and wire protocol, each piece of data is passed as part of a separate buffer, and innately can't possibly be interpreted as code. (I'm not sure that MySQL has a well-designed wire protocol -- used to be they didn't -- but even if they don't, if the official MySQL library does something wrong, that's their fault and not yours).

Comment: @Charles Duffy - Thanks for the time and comments. I did manage to get the import working using bash eventually but I did switch to using PHP as it simply has more flexibility on top of all the points you made. This was simply a side project I was doing to try learn using bash on my local Mac, wasn't for any production project (The bash script). Just wanted a fast way to import the words into mySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape `'` by `''` in mysql. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
inputfile="words.txt"
cat $inputfile | while read word; do
    echo "INSERT INTO words (word, word_size) VALUES (\"${word/\'/''}\", CHAR_LENGTH(\"${word/\'/''}\"));"
done | mysql -u root -p crossword
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty :)

The `'` should be escaped as `\'` or as `''` (double apostrophe).

The following example uses `\'`.

```
sed "s/'/\\\'/g;s/.*/INSERT INTO words (word, word_size) VALUES ('&', CHAR_LENGTH('&'));/" < words.txt | mysql -u root -p pass
```

*Ps: But, double check @chepner's comment :)*